# How to open sms box in IOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Im fetching the numbers from other screen while navigating, im using linking to open up the sms box
. While doing so when i run the same code it works in the android
[[image: Android_message_box]]

....
`{favNums} = route.params

```
const ButtonPress = () => {
    console.log('favNums', favNums);
    if (Platform.OS == 'ios') {
      Linking.openURL(`sms:${favNums}`);
    } else {
      Linking.openURL(`sms:${favNums}?body=${'Hello people'}`);
    }

  };
```

....`

This code is running when i click on a button, and this code works fine for android but when i click on the ios side it gives me this error.
[[image: Ios_message_box]](

I tried sending for single number,

```
`Linking.openURL(`sms:${281973902}`);`
```

which gave me this as a response when i clicked on the button,[image: IOS_sms_box_open],
But for multiple lets say i user array index
`Linking.openURL(`sms:${favNums[0}`);`
Its still giving me same error!

Answer (score 0):

So, i have faced this scenario earlier and then i tried changing few things in the code,

```
const ButtonPress = () => {
let numbers = '';
favNums.forEach(phoneNumber => {
  numbers += `${phoneNumber},`;
});
numbers = numbers.slice(0, -1);
console.log('numbers', numbers);

const url =
  Platform.OS === 'android'
    ? `sms:${numbers}?body=${'hello'}`
    : `sms://open?addresses=${numbers}&body=${'hello'}`;

Linking.openURL(url);
```

};

And then it did open up the sms box in IOS, but wasn't showing any name, then i made the build from xcode and re-checked in real device. And it started working no matter which contact i chose to send the msg it was working fine. Maybe the issue relies in simulator, so make sure to check in the real device.